# How do I properly setup Android Studio to work with GenyMotion?

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

I am using Android Studio 1.1 and GenyMotion 2.3.1

I have followed many guides online but I am unable to run my apks through Genymotion.

This is what I get when I try to run something:-

[image]

When I click "**Run**" I get a "**Configuration is Still Incorrect. Do you want to edit it again.?**" with two options :- "**Edit**" and "**Continue Anyway**".

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the genymotion device you have downloaded?

Comment: The error is not related to Genymotion. Can you paste the content of your build.gradle file?

Comment: Sorry nothing related to your build.gradle you can forget my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the Genymotion plugin. Go through this. [Genymotion Plugin for Android Studio](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#genymotion-plugin-for-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Android Studio is not picking up your module (so not a Genymotion problem). Ensure that one of the first lines in your module (not root project) `build.gradle` is this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

**On second thought** the problem might be your folder structure. You opened the root project in `...../bartalk-master` but it is in reality located in `...../bartalk-master/bartalk-master`. Fix this and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion devices behave with ADB exactly like any USB device you plug into your computer.

Considering your problem the window appears because Android Studio does not find a device to connect with : no USB device, no AVD (official emulator), and no Genymotion instance.

The `Target Device` section, on the window, allows you to choose on what kind if device you want to launch your app. If you want to use Genymotion you can let it set `Show chooser dialog` or whether `USB Devices`.

Now, what you should do is to be careful to have a Genymotion instance already launched before running your app.

To be sure the connection is already done you can try to type `adb devices` you should see something like this:

```
List of devices attached 
192.168.56.101:5555 device
```

The `<ip>:<port> device` line is the Genymotion instance currently running.

Please give more details about your situation if this does not solve your problem.